# what to do when vs-code remote C++ debugging asks to set gnutarget format-name

Tags: remote, c++, gdb, visual-studio-code

I am on to debugging remote C++ program running on raspberry pi on ubuntu. I have followed https://medium.com/@spe_/debugging-c-c-programs-remotely-using-visual-studio-code-and-gdbserver-559d3434fb78. But upon start of debugging I get

```
GDB failed with message: "/MyProjec/MyProgram": not in executable format: File format is ambiguous.
Matching formats: elf32-littlearm elf32-littlearm-symbian elf32-littlearm-vxworks.
Use "set gnutarget format-name" to specify the format.
​
```

where to set `gnutarget format-name`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Where do I `set gnutarget format-name`?

In your `gdb.ini` or `.gdbinit` file as appropriate.

> **The `.gdbinit` File**
>
> Upon startup, GDB reads and executes an initialization file named
>   `.gdbinit`. It can contain any command (eg set and break), and more. For
>   example, "set listsize" and "set prompt" can go into .gdbinit. There
>   are two locations where GDB will look for this file (in order):
>
> - In your home directory
> - In the current directory
>
> You can put commands to be executed for all your programming projects
>   in `$HOME/.gdbinit` and project-specific commands in `$PWD/.gdbinit`.
>
> You can comment your `.gdbinit` files with bash's `#`. And blank lines,
>   of course, are ignored.

[Peter's gdb Tutorial: Initialization, Listing, And Running](http://www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/03-Initialization,_Listing,_And_Running.php)

Example:

**A sample `gdb.ini` file**

> Here you have a sample `gdb.ini` file listing, which gives better
>   results when using `gdb`. Under linux you should put this in a
>   `.gdbinit` file in your home directory or the current directory.
>
> ```
> set print demangle off  
> set gnutarget auto  
> set verbose on  
> set complaints 1000  
> dir ./rtl/dosv2  
> set language c++  
> set print vtbl on  
> set print object on  
> set print sym on  
> set print pretty on  
> disp /i $eip  
>
> define pst  
> set $pos=&$arg0  
> set $strlen = {byte}$pos  
> print {char}&$arg0.st@($strlen+1)  
> end  
>
> document pst  
>   Print out a Pascal string  
> end
> ```

Source [E A sample gdb.ini file](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap5.html#x191-198000E)